# Date, arithmetic, and ternary operator in one line

Tags: bash, shell-script, arithmetic

I have a simple code to ensure a script takes at least x seconds (500 here) on Ubuntu

```
t1=$(date +%s)
# script is here
t2=$(date +%s)
let "t = 500 - $t2 + $t1"
(( t = t>0 ? t : 1 ))
sleep $t
```

The code works perfectly, but I believe my coding is not efficient, and these three lines

```
t2=$(date +%s)
let "t = 500 - $t2 + $t1"
(( t = t>0 ? t : 1 ))
```

should be expressed in one single line. My question is how to improve the code.

Comment: Is this a Linux platform, or some UNIX? (More specifically, do you have GNU `date`?)

Comment: There is much to be said for not sacrificing readability for perceived efficiency.  If you compress that all into an inscrutable one-liner running as a subshell expansion as a parameter for `sleep`, how are you going to unravel that when someone calls you at 4 in the morning the day after a most raucous party to debug it when it goes sideways?

Comment: You could lose the `t` and `t2` entirely, but make sure your phone is switched off at 4am. `sleep $( printf "%d\n" $(( 500 - ($(date +%s) - t1) )) | sed 's/^-.*/1/' )`

Comment: @roaima Sorry for being vague. I updated the question. I haven't got stuck anywhere. I just want to improve my code, as I believe it is not the efficient way.

Comment: @DopeGhoti very good point indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I would do it using `bash` special parameter `SECONDS`:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                  

SECONDS=0
# script is here                                                                                                                                                                             
sleep "$(( 500 > SECONDS ? 500 - SECONDS : 1 ))"
```

Normally `SECONDS` returns time (in seconds) since the script has started, but one can assign any value to (re)set the timer.

Comment: Zeroing `SECONDS` doesn't hurt, and at least makes the initial value explicit, but since it tells the time since the script started you don't _have to_ zero it. Unless the script does something else first, of course.

Answer (score 4):

What your script is, is non-portable (since you're using `let` and `(( .. ))`), confusing (since you're using *both* `let` and `(( .. ))`), lacking in documentation (there are no comments, and the variable names are non-descriptive), and marginally unsafe (since you haven't quoted the expansion of `$t`).

If you want a rewrite, here's mine:

```
#!/bin/sh

min_duration=500
t_start=$(date +%s)
# script is here
t_end=$(date +%s)
elapsed=$(( t_end - t_start ))

# sleep long enough to make sure 'min_duration' seconds has elapsed, 
# but at least 1 second
sleep "$(( elapsed < min_duration ? min_duration - elapsed : 1 ))"
```

Comment: Is there any practical difference between your `: "$(( elapsed = t_end - t_start ))"` and simply `(( elapsed = t_end - t_start ))`?

Comment: @roaima The exit status when the calculation results in a zero. It matters when running under `set -e`.  Personally, I think I would have used `elapsed=$(( ... ))`.  Also notice that he's writing for `/bin/sh`, not `bash`.

Comment: @roaima, I was just thinking about the portability point. At least `dash` and `busybox` don't support `(( .. ))`. With Bash, I'd use `(( .. ))` since it looks less ugly to me. The exit status shouldn't matter (well, unless someone uses `set -e`, but let's not go there...)

Comment: @Kusalananda, argh, of course with `elapsed=$((..))`... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A simple alternative is to just run sleep in in the background and then `wait` for it after running the other code.

```
  #!/bin/bash

  sleep 500 &
  # script is here
  wait
```